# What does "component" prop means in MUI component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm new to React and HTML. Now I'm using MUI and React to build up my own website.
Now I'm trying to set a "Upload button", which when I click it, it will let me select a img file.

Here's the official implement

```
<Button variant="contained" component="label">
  Upload
  <input hidden accept="image/*" multiple type="file" />
</Button>
<IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="label">
  <input hidden accept="image/*" type="file" />
  <PhotoCamera />
</IconButton>
```

It works. However, when I delete the `component="label"` it just doesn't work.

So I'm just wondering what the "component" means...

According to https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/ , it means "The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.". But because I'm new to HTML, I just dont know why when I let `component="label"`, the input can work but otherwise it doesn't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) are a keyword in React which is effectively a JavaScript class or function that you can use to calculate some logic and/or render HTML to the page.

In the button *component* from the MUI library, it is possible to pass in one of these components to render in for that button and provide some useful logic or styling in that area. In the case of a string, you can provide the name of default HTML elements (think `input`, `div`, `a` etc) and MUI will render one of these elements instead. In this case you are selecting a `label` elemnet which is commonly used alongside an `input` element.

Comment: Got that, thanks. So I guess `component="label"` means that the button is the <label> of <input>? But in the code, it looks like that <Button> is the parent component of <input>, its looks weird that the parent component is the <label> of its child components...

Comment: @SJoJoK it would be easier for you if you would learn HTML first and then start to use react

Comment: You are right @SJoJoK. It can be beneficial to know HTML prior to working with MUI. That library does some interesting stuff to abstract away the base HTML elements in favor of theirs but knowing what they are using underneath that can help a ton.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I'm gonna learn some HTML.